# How to add SAP HANA:View with Input-Parameter to SmartTable XML SAPUI5

Tags: xml, odata, sapui5, hana-xs

I'm trying to add a view Entity Set to a Smart table in XML but the Entityset got an Input parameter.

```
"MYAPP.CalculationViews::FIVELEVELANALYSE" as "FIVELEVELANALYSE" key generate local "EMP_ID" parameters via entity "5LevelSYS" results property "Execute";
```

I can use *5LevelSYS(1)/Execute* to get the correct results.
I added a SelectionVariant Parameter to my Annotation file.

```
<Annotation Term="UI.SelectionVariant">
    <Record Type="UI.SelectionVariantType">
        <PropertyValue Property="Parameters">
            <Collection>
                <Record Type="UI.Parameter">
                    <PropertyValue Property="PropertyName" PropertyPath="sysidinput" />
                    <PropertyValue Property="PropertyValue" String="1" />
                </Record>
            </Collection>
        </PropertyValue>
        <PropertyValue Property="SelectOptions" />
    </Record>
</Annotation>
```

Got that from [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/topic/b40e5ae5cdd647c490bd03b9d5f98d56)

My Smarttable looks like that

```
smartTable:SmartTable id="LineItemsSmartTable" entitySet="5LevelSYS" smartFilterId="smartFilterBar" tableType="ResponsiveTable"
        useVariantManagement="true" useTablePersonalisation="true" header="Line Items" useExportToExcel="true" beforeExport="onBeforeExport"  tableBindingPath="Items"
        showRowCount="true" persistencyKey="SmartTableAnalytical_Explored" enableAutoBinding="true" app:useSmartField="true" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
        <!-- layout data used to make the table growing but the filter bar fixed -->
        <smartTable:layoutData>
            <FlexItemData growFactor="1" baseSize="0%"/>
        </smartTable:layoutData>
    </smartTable:SmartTable>
```

I'm not sure what I have to write into entitySet for the Smarttable?
I also added the Lineitem but that would be to much code for the Questions.
The example says something about editing the manifest but I can't find the correct position to add the line. Maybe that's my Problem?

Thanks
Tobias